# Spark: Not able to use accumulator on a tuple/count using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to replace `reduceByKey` with accumulator logic for word count.

## wc.txt

> Hello how are are you

Here's what I've got so far:

```
val words = sc.textFile("wc.txt").flatMap(_.split(" "))
val accum = sc.accumulator(0,"myacc")
for (i <- 1 to words.count.toInt) 
    foreach( x => accum+ =x)
    .....
```

How to proceed about it. Any thoughts or ideas are appreciated.

Comment: What's `foreach` in your code? I don't see how it could call `RDD.foreach` in case you wanted to use it?

Comment: Thanks, Actually the expected output is (Hello,1), (are,2), (how,1),(you,1)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this example does not compile. So what's the compilation error telling you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, using Accumulators for this is cumbersome and not recommended - but for completeness - here's how it can be done (at least with Spark versions **1.6 <= V <= 2.1**). Do note that this uses a deprecated API that will not be a part of next versions.

You'll need a `Map[String, Long]` accumulator, which is not available by default, so you'll need to create your own `AccumulableParam` implementation and use it implicitly:

```
// some data:
val words = sc.parallelize(Seq("Hello how are are you")).flatMap(_.split(" "))

// aliasing the type, just for convenience
type AggMap = Map[String, Long]

// creating an implicit AccumulableParam that counts by String key
implicit val param: AccumulableParam[AggMap, String] = new AccumulableParam[AggMap, String] {
  // increase matching value by 1, or create it if missing
  override def addAccumulator(r: AggMap, t: String): AggMap = 
    r.updated(t, r.getOrElse(t, 0L) + 1L)

  // merge two maps by summing matching values 
  override def addInPlace(r1: AggMap, r2: AggMap): AggMap = 
    r1 ++ r2.map { case (k, v) => k -> (v + r1.getOrElse(k, 0L)) }

  // start with an empty map
  override def zero(initialValue: AggMap): AggMap = Map.empty
}

// create the accumulator; This will use the above `param` implicitly
val acc = sc.accumulable[AggMap, String](Map.empty[String, Long])

// add each word to accumulator; the `count()` can be replaced by any Spark action - 
// we just need to trigger the calculation of the mapped RDD 
words.map(w => { acc.add(w); w }).count()

// after the action, we acn read the value of the accumulator
val result: AggMap = acc.value

result.foreach(println)
// (Hello,1)
// (how,1)
// (are,2)
// (you,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to count all words in you text file using Spark accumulator, in this case you can use:

```
words.foreach(_ => accum.add(1L))
```

Comment: Thanks. But the final out put should be (Hello,1), (are,2), (how,1),(you,1)

Comment: In this case using accumulators is not good idea... The only solution with accumulators that I can propose is to create dedicated accumulator for each distinct word and in foreach operation increment relevant accumulator. Obvious drawback is that you need to know list of distinct words upfront...